# xp_logevent warning entry

Tags: sql-server

i couldnt able to make a message entry as a warning in system event log using xp_logevent

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Answer (score 1):

here is the documentation on [xp_logevent (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186244.aspx)

when I ran this example (from the above documentation on SQL Server 2005 Enterprise on Windows Server 2003 Enterprise ):

```
--I'm not sure why they declare their local variables with @@, but this code is right from the documentation
DECLARE @@TABNAME varchar(30)
DECLARE @@USERNAME varchar(30)
DECLARE @@MESSAGE varchar(255)
SET @@TABNAME = 'customers'
SET @@USERNAME = USER_NAME()
SELECT @@MESSAGE = 'The table ' + @@TABNAME + ' is not owned by the user 
   ' + @@USERNAME + '.'

USE master
EXEC xp_logevent 60000, @@MESSAGE, informational
```

there was a message in the system log:

```
Type: Informational
Source: MSSQLSERVER
Category: (2)
Event: 17061
User: N/A
Description: Error: 60000 Severity: 10 State: 1 The table customers is not owned by the user dbo.
```